# Xamarin Forms app badge number with Firebase Push Notification

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Any way can update the badge number beside the app icon when receive push notification?(ex: the outlook app in attachment image [as attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2b7N.png)) Right now I only able to update it when the app in open.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Read from other source, tried include badge number in the payload.But the result still same, not able to update the badge number when received push notification and app is closed/killed.

Comment: Could you edit your post, to elaborate what exactly you did and how you did it?

Comment: @PaulKertscher I follow this https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin and coded, ended up i able to receive push notification. But the app icon's badge was not able to update

Comment: This might or might not be fine, but I'd like *you* to *edit* the question that someone here might give a sufficient answer. Please see [ask].

Comment: Thanks @PaulKertscher. I will aware my question next time.